# range variable not detecting floating points numeric values inside the given range

Tags: python, range

the code prints 9 even thought 6.33 falls into the range in the 3rd if statement not zero but within the range (5,8)

i was expecting it to print 3
the code

```
address="xyz"
size="6.33"
if address == 0 and float(size) in range(1, 5):
    print("1")
elif address == 0 and float(size) in range(5, 8):          
    print("2")
elif address != 0 and float(size) in range(5, 8):         
    print("3")
elif address == 0 and float(size) in range(8, 10):        
    print("4")
elif address != 0 and float(size) in range(10, 19):         
    print("5")
elif address == 0 and float(size) in range(10, 19):          
    print("6")
elif address != 0 and float(size) in range(20, 100):         
    print("7")
elif address != 0 and float(size) in range(20, 100):   
    print("8")
else:           
    print("9")
```

how do i fix the code so that it is able to detect floating point values in the given range

Comment: conditions for printing 7 and 8 are identical. Please correct it. `range` will generate only integers.

Comment: thks i just noticed i will change it in the actual code and make it  ==0 and !=0 
i will leave as it is over here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range` generates only integers. For example, `range(2,6)` will generate (2,3,4,5).

Your problem can be solved by:

```py
address="xyz"
size="6.33"
if address == 0 and float(size)>=1 and  float(size)<5:
    print("1")
elif address == 0 and float(size)>=5 and  float(size)<8:          
    print("2")
elif address != 0 and float(size)>=5 and  float(size)<8:         
    print("3")
elif address == 0 and float(size)>=8 and  float(size)<10:        
    print("4")
elif address != 0 and float(size)>=10 and  float(size)<19:         
    print("5")
elif address == 0 and float(size)>=10 and  float(size)<19:          
    print("6")
elif address != 0 and float(size)>=20 and  float(size)<100:         
    print("7")
elif address == 0 and float(size)>=20 and  float(size)<100:   
    print("8")
else:           
    print("9")
```

Or more efficiently, using nested conditions,

```py
address="xyz"
size="6.33"
if address == 0:
    if float(size)>=1 and  float(size)<5:
        print("1")
    elif float(size)>=5 and float(size)<8:          
        print("2")
    elif float(size)>=8 and float(size)<10:          
        print("4")
    elif float(size)>=10 and float(size)<19:          
        print("6")
    elif float(size)>=20 and float(size)<100:          
        print("8")
    else:
        print("9")
else:
    if float(size)>=5 and float(size)<8:          
        print("3")
    elif float(size)>=10 and float(size)<19:          
        print("5")
    elif float(size)>=20 and float(size)<100:          
        print("7")
    else:
        print("9")
```

Answer (score 0):

All right, here there is more to unpack:

`range(3)` is more like `[0, 1, 2]`, i.e. sequence of integers, not an interval of real values. So:

```
>>> 1 in range(3)
True
>>> 1.5 in range(3)
False
```

But it is also true that

```
>>> 1.0 in range(3)
```

because `x in s` is `True` if an item of `s` is equal to `x`, else `False` and also:

```
>>> 1 == 1.0
True
```

See official documentation on Common Sequence Operations: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common

But generally using equality and floating point numbers is a bad idea as it can lead to surprising results due to binary representation of floating point numbers:

```
>>> 0.3 + 0.3 == 0.6
True
>>> 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3 == 0.9
False
>>> 10 * (0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3) == 9
True
```

One reasonable way how to fix your code is:

```
address = "xyz"
size = float("6.33")  # single conversion here
if address == 0 and 1 <= size < 5:
    print("1")
# ...
elif address != 0 and 20 <= size < 100:   
    print("8")
else:           
    print("9")
```

Chained comparison (e.g. `1 < 2 < 3`) is described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons